# Angular Slick autoplaySpeed isn't working

Tags: angularjs, slick.js

I'm using 'Angular Slick' to make a carousel, everthings working as I wanted, except for 'autoplaySpeed' property, when I use it, it is not working, in the docs there is nothing related to...

HTML:

```
    <slick init-onload="false" slick-apply='slickApply' autoplaySpeed="3000" data="dataLoaded" autoplay="true" slides-to-show="1" dots="true">
        <div ng-repeat="item in carouselItems">
            <h2 class="starter-benefits__title">{{item.title | translate}}</h2>
            <h6 class="starter-benefits__info">{{item.message | translate}}</h6>
        </div>
    </slick>
```

JS.

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('initCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.carouselItems = [];
        $timeout(function() {

            $scope.carouselItems = [
                {
                    title: 'LABEL_INIT_CAROUSEL_FIRST_TITLE',
                    message: 'LABEL_INIT_CAROUSEL_FIRST_MESSAGE'
                },
                {
                    title: 'LABEL_INIT_CAROUSEL_SECOND_TITLE',
                    message: 'LABEL_INIT_CAROUSEL_SECOND_MESSAGE'
                },
                {
                    title: 'LABEL_INIT_CAROUSEL_THIRD_TITLE',
                    message: 'LABEL_INIT_CAROUSEL_THIRD_MESSAGE'
                },
                {
                    title: 'LABEL_INIT_CAROUSEL_FOURTH_TITLE',
                    message: 'LABEL_INIT_CAROUSEL_FOURTH_MESSAGE'
                }
            ];

            $scope.dataLoaded = true;

        }, 2000);
    });
```

Hope guys can help me figure out what's going on.

Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't it be "autoplay-speed" ?

Comment: What a... :S didn't try with this one, thank you so much, it worked!! :)

Comment: @o4ohel - such a small detail, proper answer.